# Finding right thread for profiles mysql query

Tags: mysql, user-profile

I am trying to write a query which will find the best matching discussions for user profiles.

There are two tables here:

Thread table - each thread is tagged with numeric tagids (in separate columns tagid1, tagid2... tagid10). Each tagid is basically keywords which occur in the thread. 
We also have the prominence (in separate columns - prominence1, prominence2... prominence10)- which is how many times the keyword occurs in the thread.

```
For example: 
threadid 123
tagids 1234, 12345, 12234, 11232, 11232, 112343, 1123224
prominence 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2
```

User table - each userid is tagged with numeric tagids (in separate columns tagid1, tagid2... tagid10) which are most prominent (in separate columns - prominence1, prominence2... prominence10) for the user. 
Prominence here is calculated by how many times a user has participated in a thread which has a particular tag.

```
For example:
userid 12334
tagids 1234, 5654, 45476, 4553, 44653, 6456432, 645645
prominence 6, 3, 2, 5, 2, 6, 1
```

If we have these two sets of data - how do I find the best matching threads for each user profile if I have to display a list of best matching threads?

Kindly help, I need some direction towards the logic which needs to be used to find the best matches.

Comment: Okay... the answer seems to be - multiply the prominence of both and see which threads have the highest score for the users list of tags.